# Subgroup of coprime order with automorphism group is contained in center of group

Tags: group-theory, proof-writing, finite-groups, automorphism-group

I'm studying for a qualifying exam in algebra and I've come across the following problem:

> Let $G$ be a finite group with a subgroup $N$. Let $Aut(G)$ be the group of automorphisms of $G$. Prove that if $|Aut(G)|$ and $|N|$ are relatively prime, then $N$ is contained in the center of $G$.

I'm struggling to find a good way to approach this. I'm able to prove a similar result that if $|G|$ and $|Aut(G)|$ are relatively prime, then $G$ is abelian:

Let $\theta$ be a homomorphism from $G$ to the inner automorphism group of $G$, denoted $\theta:G\rightarrow Inn(G)$. Then because inner automorphisms are conjugations by fixed elements, the kernel of $\theta$ is the center of $G$, denoted $ker(\theta)=Z(G)$. By the first isomorphism theorem, it follows that $G/Z(G)\cong Inn(G)\subseteq Aut(G)$. Hence, by Lagrange's theorem, $|G/Z(G)|$ divides $|Aut(G)|$. Similarly, by consequence of Lagrange's theorem, $|G/Z(G)||Z|=|G|$, as $Z(G)$ is a normal subgroup of $G$. Since $|G/Z(G)|$ divides $|G|$ and $|Aut(G)|$, and $|G|$ and $|Aut(G)|$ are relatively prime, it follows that $|G/Z(G)|=1$, implying that $G=Z(G)$. The desired result follows. $\blacksquare$

It's not obvious to me how to transform this proof into one of the desired problem (or if there even is a good way to simply modify what I already have). If I knew that $N$ were a normal subgroup, I could potentially apply the same kind of argument using Lagrange's theorem, but I don't have that assumption. Without more information on the structure of $G$, it doesn't seem likely that I'll be able to use an element argument to show that $N\subseteq Z(G)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

First, note that $|N|$ is coprime to $|\!\operatorname{Aut}(G)|$ if and only if the order of every $n\in N$ is coprime to $|\!\operatorname{Aut}(G)|$.

Second, let $\varphi_n$ be the inner automorphism corresponding to any $n\in N$. What happens if $\varphi_n$ has nontrivial order? What does it mean if $\varphi_n$ has trivial order?

Comment: Could you elaborate? Since Alexander Gruber has helped me work out a solution in the comments to his answer, I'm inclined to accept that answer...unless this one is more elegant.

Comment: Sure! The order of $\varphi_n$ has to divide the order of both $n$ and $\operatorname{Aut}(G)$. Since those two are coprime, the order of $\varphi_n$ must be $1$. This occurs exactly when $n\in Z(G)$.

Comment: Ah, very good. Just to clarify, the order of $\varphi_n$ must divide the order of $Aut(G)$ as $\varphi_n\in Aut(G)$, but why must it divide the order of $n$?

Comment: Well, if $|n| = k$, then $\varphi_n^k = 1$. Since $\varphi_n^s = 1$ if and only if the order of $\varphi_n$ divides $s$, this means that the order of $\varphi_n$ divides $k$.

Answer (score 2):

$N/Z(G)\leq G/Z(G)$. If $N\not\leq Z(G)$, what can you say about the order of $N/Z(G)$?

Comment: Does it even make sense to talk about $N/Z$? The goal is to show that $N\leq Z$, so certainly $Z\not< N$, right?

Comment: By $N/Z(G)$, I mean the image of $N$ under the projection homomorphism $g\mapsto gZ(G)$.

Comment: Right. (Can you tell I'm rusty on my abstract algebra?) Then clearly $N/Z\leq G/Z$, as you've stated. Hence, $\frac{|G|}{|N/Z|}\leq\frac{|G|}{|G/Z|}$. So if $N\leq Z$, then $N/Z=Z$. But if $N\not\leq Z$, then $|N/Z|>|Z|$. Since $|Z|=\frac{|G|}{|G/Z|}$, then $\frac{|G|}{|N/Z|}>\frac{|G|}{|G/Z|}$, which is a contradiction.

Comment: More generally, whenever $Z$ is normal in $G$ and $[G:Z]$ is coprime to $|N|$, we can conclude that $N\leq Z$.

Comment: I think that works. I would use divisibility, as follows: $|N/Z|$ must divide both $|G/Z|$ and $|N|$. (Sorry for slow typing here, I'm on mobile.)

Comment: I like that more than what I said, because it's clear where all the hypotheses come into play. $|G/Z|$ divides $|Aut(G)|$ as explained in the question, and since $GCD(|Aut(G)|,|N|)=1$, $|N/Z|=1$. I guess this implies that $N=Z$, not $N\leq Z$ though

Comment: Well, not necessarily, for example we might have $N$ as the identity subgroup of order $1$. It's maybe bad form on the part of group theorists (but common practice) to refer to the image as $N/Z$, since that seems to imply $Z\leq N$. What is really meant is the image $\pi(N)$ where $\pi:G\rightarrow G/Z$ is $\pi(g)=gZ$. It's more clear written that way that $\pi(N)$ can exist, and that it's equal to $Z$ when $N$ is proper in $Z$.

Comment: Right, I was getting confused by the notation again. That provides the necessary clarification. Thank you.

Comment: What you denote by $N/Z$, I have always seen denoted $NZ/Z$, which gets rids of the problem. (See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isomorphism_theorems#Second_isomorphism_theorem for example)